# Parsing XML having multiple namespaces using python

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I am trying to parse public xml files that have many namespaces. How do I use python to extract all of the text from tag uscom:TextInput that is a child of uscom:DataTable uscom:tableDataType="NPLDocuments"? Thank you

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<uspat:IncomingDocument xmlns:uscom="urn:us:gov:doc:uspto:common" xmlns="urn:us:gov:doc:uspto:patent"
                        xmlns:uspat="urn:us:gov:doc:uspto:patent"
                        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                        xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/"
                        xmlns:xdp="http://ns.adobe.com/xdp/"
                        xmlns:com="http://www.wipo.int/standards/XMLSchema/ST96/Common"
                        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:us:gov:doc:uspto:patent XML_Schema/V2_0/USPatent/Document/IncomingDocument_V2_0.xsd"
                        com:fileName="14654539.2015-08-31.IE0IVLL4PXXIFW3.IDS.xml"
                        com:id="ID_1">
   <uspat:DocumentMetadata com:id="ID_2">
      <uscom:DocumentCode>IDS</uscom:DocumentCode>
      <uscom:ApplicationNumberText uscom:electronicText="14654539">14654539</uscom:ApplicationNumberText>
      <uscom:FormVersionNumber>2.0</uscom:FormVersionNumber>
      <com:PageTotalQuantity>4</com:PageTotalQuantity>
      <uscom:DocumentSourceIdentifier uscom:sourceKindCategory="Self" uscom:systemName="PATI">IE0IVLL4PXXIFW3</uscom:DocumentSourceIdentifier>
      <uscom:MailroomDate>2015-08-31</uscom:MailroomDate>
   </uspat:DocumentMetadata>
   <uscom:FormBag>
      <uscom:Form uscom:formNumber="PTO/SB/08a (01-10)" uscom:formRevisionNumber="01-10"
                  uscom:formRevisionDate="01-01-2000"
                  uscom:formExpirationDate="07-31-2012"
                  uscom:ombFormNumber="0651-0031">
         <uscom:FormPage uscom:pageNumber="1" com:orientationCategory="Portrait" uscom:pageSize="Letter">
            <uscom:FormPageHeader uscom:verticalAlign="middle" uscom:horizontalAlign="right" com:id="header-1">
PTO/SB/08a (01-10) <com:Br/> 
Approved for use through 07/31/2012. OMB 0651-0031 <com:Br/> 
U.S. Patent and Trademark Office: U.S. DEPARTMENT OF COMMERCE <com:Br/> 
Under the Paperwork Reduction Act of 1995, no persons are required to respond to a collection of information unless it displays a valid OMB control number. <com:Br/>
               <com:Br/> 

XFA Data Version Number: v20_EFSWeb<com:Br/>
            </uscom:FormPageHeader>
            <uscom:FormPageBody>
               <com:Br/>
               <uscom:DataTable uscom:tableDataType="Page Header" uscom:border="2">
                  <uscom:TableRow>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell uscom:verticalAlign="middle" uscom:horizontalAlign="center" uscom:rowSpan="5">
                        <uscom:Heading com:headingLevelCode="H1">INFORMATION DISCLOSURE</uscom:Heading>
                        <com:Br/>
                        <uscom:Heading com:headingLevelCode="H1">STATEMENT BY APPLICANT</uscom:Heading>
                        <com:Br/>
                        <uscom:Heading com:headingLevelCode="H4">(Not for submission under 37 CFR 1.99)</uscom:Heading>
                        <com:Br/>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:horizontalAlign="left">Application Number</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell uscom:horizontalAlign="left">
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text" uscom:inputName="ApplicationNumber">14654539</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                  </uscom:TableRow>
                  <uscom:TableRow>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:horizontalAlign="left">Filing Date</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell uscom:horizontalAlign="left">
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text" uscom:inputName="FilingDate">2015-06-21</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                  </uscom:TableRow>
                  <uscom:TableRow>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:horizontalAlign="left">First Named Inventor</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell uscom:horizontalAlign="left">
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text" uscom:inputName="ApplicantName">Frank Singer</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                  </uscom:TableRow>
                  <uscom:TableRow>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:horizontalAlign="left">Art Unit</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell uscom:horizontalAlign="left">
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text" uscom:inputName="GroupArtUnit">TBD</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                  </uscom:TableRow>
                  <uscom:TableRow>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:horizontalAlign="left">Examiner Name</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell uscom:horizontalAlign="left">
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text" uscom:inputName="ExaminerName">TBD</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                  </uscom:TableRow>
               </uscom:DataTable>
               <com:Br/>
               <com:Br/>
               <uscom:DataTable uscom:border="1" uscom:tableDataType="USPatents">
                  <uscom:TableRow>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:horizontalAlign="center" uscom:colSpan="7">
                        <uscom:Heading com:headingLevelCode="H4">U.S.PATENTS</uscom:Heading>
                     </uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                  </uscom:TableRow>
                  <uscom:TableRow>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:dataCategory="ExaminerInitial" uscom:rowSpan="3">Examiner<com:Br/>Initial*</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:dataCategory="SequenceNumber" uscom:rowSpan="3">Cite<com:Br/>No</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:dataCategory="PatentNumber" uscom:rowSpan="3">Patent Number</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:dataCategory="DocumentKindCode" uscom:rowSpan="3">Kind<com:Br/>Code</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:dataCategory="IssueDate" uscom:rowSpan="3">Issue Date</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:dataCategory="PersonName" uscom:rowSpan="3">Name of Patentee or Applicant<com:Br/> of cited Document </uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:dataCategory="PriorArtCitationText" uscom:rowSpan="3">Pages,Columns,Lines where<com:Br/>Relevant Passages or Relevant<com:Br/>Figures Appear</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                  </uscom:TableRow>
                  <uscom:TableRow>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell/>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">1</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text"/>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text"/>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text"/>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text"/>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text"/>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                  </uscom:TableRow>
               </uscom:DataTable>
               <com:Br/>
               <uscom:DataTable uscom:tableDataType="USPreGrantPublications" uscom:border="2">
                  <uscom:TableRow>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:horizontalAlign="center" uscom:colSpan="7">
                        <uscom:Heading com:headingLevelCode="H4">U.S.PATENT APPLICATION PUBLICATIONS</uscom:Heading>
                     </uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                  </uscom:TableRow>
                  <uscom:TableRow>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:dataCategory="ExaminerInitial" uscom:rowSpan="3">Examiner<com:Br/>Initial*</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:dataCategory="SequenceNumber" uscom:rowSpan="3">Cite No</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:dataCategory="PublicationNumber" uscom:rowSpan="3">Publication<com:Br/>Number</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:dataCategory="DocumentKindCode" uscom:rowSpan="3">Kind<com:Br/>Code</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:dataCategory="PublicationDate" uscom:rowSpan="3">Publication<com:Br/>Date</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:dataCategory="PersonName" uscom:rowSpan="3">Name of Patentee or Applicant<com:Br/> of cited Document </uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:dataCategory="PriorArtCitationText" uscom:rowSpan="3">Pages,Columns,Lines where<com:Br/>Relevant Passages or Relevant<com:Br/>Figures Appear</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                  </uscom:TableRow>
                  <uscom:TableRow>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell/>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">1</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">20100328617</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">A1</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">2010-12-30</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">Masuda</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text"/>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                  </uscom:TableRow>
                  <uscom:TableRow>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell/>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">2</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">20110249460</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">A1</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">2011-10-13</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">Kushimoto</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text"/>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                  </uscom:TableRow>

                     <uscom:TableDataCell/>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">4</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">20130314896</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">A1</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">2013-11-28</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">Finsterbusch</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text"/>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                  </uscom:TableRow>
               </uscom:DataTable>
               <com:Br/>
               <uscom:DataTable uscom:tableDataType="ForeignDocuments" uscom:border="2">
                  <uscom:TableRow>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:horizontalAlign="center" uscom:colSpan="9">
                        <uscom:Heading com:headingLevelCode="H4">FOREIGN PATENT DOCUMENTS</uscom:Heading>
                     </uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                  </uscom:TableRow>
                  <uscom:TableRow>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:dataCategory="ExaminerInitial" uscom:rowSpan="4">Examiner<com:Br/>Initial*</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:dataCategory="SequenceNumber" uscom:rowSpan="4">Cite<com:Br/>No</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:dataCategory="DocumentNumber" uscom:rowSpan="4">Foreign Document<com:Br/>Number</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:dataCategory="IPOfficeCode" uscom:rowSpan="4">Country<com:Br/>Code</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:dataCategory="DocumentKindCode" uscom:rowSpan="4">Kind<com:Br/>Code</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:dataCategory="PublicationDate" uscom:rowSpan="4">Publication<com:Br/>Date</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:dataCategory="PersonName" uscom:rowSpan="4">Name of Patentee or <com:Br/>Applicant of cited<com:Br/>Document</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:dataCategory="PriorArtCitationText" uscom:rowSpan="4">Pages,Columns,Lines<com:Br/>where Relevant<com:Br/>Passages or Relevant<com:Br/>Figures Appear</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:dataCategory="EnglishTranslationProvidedIndicator" uscom:rowSpan="4">T</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                  </uscom:TableRow>
                  <uscom:TableRow>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell/>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text"/>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">102007055480</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">DE</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">B3</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">2009-08-13</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">Audi AG</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text"/>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">yes</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                  </uscom:TableRow>
                  <uscom:TableRow>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell/>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text"/>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">102011003665</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">DE</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">A1</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">2012-08-09</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">OSRAM AG</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">U.S. Equivalent:&#xD;2013/0314896 A1</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">no</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                  </uscom:TableRow>

                     <uscom:TableDataCell/>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text"/>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">2492579</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">EP</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">A2</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">2012-08-29</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">Stanley Electric Co., LTD</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text"/>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">no</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                  </uscom:TableRow>
               </uscom:DataTable>
               <com:Br/>
               <uscom:DataTable uscom:tableDataType="NPLDocuments" uscom:border="2">
                  <uscom:TableRow>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:horizontalAlign="center" uscom:colSpan="7">
                        <uscom:Heading com:headingLevelCode="H4">NON-PATENT LITERATURE DOCUMENTS</uscom:Heading>
                     </uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                  </uscom:TableRow>
                  <uscom:TableRow>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:dataCategory="ExaminerInitial" uscom:rowSpan="3">Examiner<com:Br/>Initials*</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:dataCategory="SequenceNumber" uscom:rowSpan="3">Cite<com:Br/>No</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:dataCategory="PriorArtCitationText" uscom:rowSpan="3">Include name of the author (in CAPITAL LETTERS), title of the article (when appropriate), title of the item<com:Br/>(book, magazine, journal, serial, symposium, catalog, etc), date, pages(s), volume-issue number(s),<com:Br/>publisher, city and/or country where published.</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell uscom:dataCategory="EnglishTranslationProvidedIndicator" uscom:rowSpan="3">T</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                  </uscom:TableRow>
                  <uscom:TableRow>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell/>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text"/>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <!--I want the text of these tags below-->
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">SUCKLING, J., et al., "Laser Headlight for Next Generation Automotive Lighting," 9th international symposium on automotive lighting, Darmstadt, 2011, pp. 271-280.</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell>
                        <uscom:TextInput uscom:textInputCategory="text">Junior, J., et al., "LED Headlight for Amazing Generation Automotive Lighting," 9th international symposium on automotive lighting, Domstag, 2012, pp. 271-280.</uscom:TextInput>
                     </uscom:TableDataCell>
                  </uscom:TableRow>
               </uscom:DataTable>
               <com:Br/>
               <uscom:DataTable uscom:tableDataType="Page Footer" uscom:border="2">
                  <uscom:TableRow>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell>Examiner Signature</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell/>
                     <uscom:TableHeaderCell>Date Considered</uscom:TableHeaderCell>
                     <uscom:TableDataCell/>
                  </uscom:TableRow>
               </uscom:DataTable>
               <com:Br/>
               <com:Br/>
            </uscom:FormPageBody>
            <uscom:FormPageFooter uscom:verticalAlign="top" uscom:horizontalAlign="left" com:id="footer-1">
*EXAMINER: Initial if reference considered, whether or not citation is conformance with MPEP 609. Draw line through citation if not conformance and not considered. Include copy of this form with next communication to Applicant.
<com:OL>
                  <com:LI>
                     <com:Sup>1</com:Sup>Applicant's unique citation designation number (optional)</com:LI>
                  <com:LI>
                     <com:Sup>2</com:Sup>See  Kind Codes of USPTO Patent Documents at www.uspto.gov or MPEP 901.04.</com:LI>

               </com:OL>
The collection of information is required by 37 CFR 1.97 and 1.98. The information is required to obtain or retain a benefit by the public which is to file (and by the USPTO to process) an application. Confidentiality is governed by 35 U.S.C 122 and 37 CFR 1.14. This collection is estimated to take 2 hours to complete, including gathering, preparing, and submitting the completed application form to the USPTO. Time will vary depending upon the individual case. Any comments on the amount of time you require to complete this form and/or suggestions for reducing this burden, should be sent to the Chief Information Officer, U.S. Patent and Trademark Office, U.S. Department of Commerce, P.O. Boc 1450, Alexandria, VA 22313-1450. DO NOT SEND FEES OR COMPLETED FORMS TO THIS ADDRESS. <com:B>TO: Commissioner for Patents, P.O, Box 1450, Alexandria, VA 22313-1450.</com:B>
               <uscom:P>
                  <com:I>If you need assistance in completing the form, call 1-800-PTO-9199 and select option 2.</com:I>
               </uscom:P>
            </uscom:FormPageFooter>
         </uscom:FormPage>
      </uscom:Form>
   </uscom:FormBag>
</uspat:IncomingDocument>
```

Comment: You need to show your current code. Also, there are many examples that show exactly how to deal with this, have you tried any of them? What did not work?

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate of a particular question, but there are actually a *ton* of questions that qualify as duplicates for this one.  If you don't like the one I picked, look at one of the others.